# Firewall between DMZ and DMZ Host Location

Tags: cisco

**I found this link from Oracle:**

[Oracle Application in DMZ (Demilitarized Zone)](https://blogs.oracle.com/prajkumar/oracle-application-in-dmz-demilitarized-zone)

**Here is the network topology:**

[image: DMZ Topology]

**And I have the following questions:**

1). What is the firewall between "Internet" and "DMZ External Server"? Is it a Cisco hardware router or a Linux ipables firewall or a Windows firewall?

2). What is the firewall between "DMZ External Server" and "Database"? Is it the second Cisco hardware router or the second Linux iptables firewall or the second Windows firewall?

3). How many NIC cards should be used for the "DMZ External Server"? As I understood, the DMZ host should use two NICs. One for Internet access, and the other for Internal network.

4). Is it possible to use only one NIC card for the "DMZ External Server" in that case?

5). Where is the "DMZ External Server" located? Is it located inside the company or outside the company?

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1+2) A firewall is any device you use as a firewall. There's a great number of different vendors building hardware, virtual and software firewalls.

In the diagram, the different zones are separated by firewalls. These can be different appliances, two pieces of the same appliance or a single firewall with two instances or simply a single firewall separating multiple zones.

3+4) That depends on your DMZ design. You can use two NICs or just one.

5) The DMZ is often located on the company premises. However, with the cloud computing advances it could be 'anywhere'.